# Injection of autowired dependencies failed in many to many relation spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity
public class Customer {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "vidoes", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}) 
    private List<Video> vidoes;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Video {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String title;   

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "videos_customers",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "videos_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customers_id"))
    private List<Customer> customer;

}
```

in CustomerRepository I want to declare a method to findByVideo(Video video) as

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {
    List<Customer> findByVideo(Video video);

}
```

the above declaration gives me exception as

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.project.db.repository.CustomerRepository com.project.db.service.CuctomerService.customerRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property video found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.project.db.repository.CustomerRepository com.project.db.service.CustomerService.customerRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property video found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 23 more
```

main reason is

> No property video found for type Customer!

## UPDATE

Through following I can save data to Customer, Video, Videos_Customers Tables

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class InitializeDatabaseService {

    @Autowired
    private VideoRepository videoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        customer.setName("Raiese Turur Khan");

        customerRepository.save(customer);

        Customer customer2 = new Customer();
        customer2.setName("Gul Mar Jaan Zardan");

        customerRepository.save(customer2);

        Video video1 = new Video();         
        video1.setTitle("Video Title");
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        customers.add(customer);
        customers.add(customer2);
        video1.setCustomers(customers);
        videoRepository.save(video1);

        Video video2 = new Video();         
        video2.setTitle("Video Title");
        List<Customer> customers2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        customers2.add(customer);
        customers2.add(customer2);
        video2.setCustomers(customers2);
        videoRepository.save(video2);       

    }
}
```

I have searched the net a lot but can not find any good tutorial or resource for resolving the issue in Many-to-Many mapping like above.

Comment: How is it supposed to know that the filed `vidoes` is the `video` property?

Comment: @zapl Ok so should I do something like this `List<Customer> findByVideo(List<Video> vidoes)`.

Comment: I have to find List of Customers with Video id

Comment: mappedBy = "customer". This is in ANY BASIC JPA TUTORIAL

Comment: @NeilStockton please tell where to add the `mappedBy = "customer"` which is in __ANY BASIC JPA TUTORIAL__

Comment: in place of your other "mappedBy" (that is wrong). mappedBy identifies the field in the other class that links back to this